# Capture pictues in blackberry application using VideoControl only works on emulator and not device

Tags: blackberry, java-me, camera, blackberry-simulator

This is only some of the code because other parts of it are spread out but on the simulator for blackberry curve this adds a VideoControl to the manager and shows up fine with another button that actually captures the picture. However, when I run this on an actual Blackberry curve (version 6 I think) it doesn't display this on the screen.

```
try 
     {
         _p = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer("capture://video?encoding=jpeg&width=1024&height=768");
         _p.realize();
         _videoControl = (VideoControl) _p.getControl("VideoControl");

         if (_videoControl != null)
         {
             videoField = (Field) _videoControl.initDisplayMode (VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field");
          //   _videoControl.setDisplayFullScreen(true);
             _videoControl.setVisible(true);
            // EnhancedFocusControl efc = (EnhancedFocusControl)p.getControl("net.rim.device.api.amms.control.camera.EnhancedFocusControl");
            // efc.startAutoFocus();
             _p.start();


             if(videoField != null)
             {
                 add(videoField);
             }
         } 
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         Dialog.alert(e.toString());
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience the way of image taking you use has appeared very unreliable (it worked fine only on a limited number of devices), so I stopped using it. Use native Camera app instead - it works fine on all devices.

Comment: Can u guide me that how to use native camera app ?.. i am new in BB.

Comment: @KinjalShah: It was years ago, so I don't remember the details. Though I can say one need to use `FileSystemJournalListener` and `Invoke` API. As a starting point (I've just googled it) take a look here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Still-valid-to-use-FileJournalListener-to-capture-camera-image/m-p/598208

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the time when things work on the emulator but not device it's permissions related, have you checked ApplicationPermissionsManager?

Word of warning, from OS4.5 to 6 a lot of stuff has been deprecated so be sure you check you have the right permissions for the models you are working with.
e.g. `ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_SCREEN_CAPTURE` was deprecated in 4.6 I think.